# When are there injective $A$-linear maps $I\to A/I$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, deformation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite type $k$-algebra and $I\subset A$ a nonzero ideal. Here $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

> *Question*. When is there an injective $A$-linear map $I\to A/I$? When is there none?

Some context. The vector space $\textrm{Hom}_A(I,A/I)$ is the set of first order deformations of $X=\textrm{Spec }A/I$ inside $Y=\textrm{Spec }A$. I was wondering if the injective maps $I\to A/I$ would have a special meaning in terms of deformation theory, but first I would need to understand when there is any at all. Thinking about the identification $$\textrm{Hom}_A(I,A/I)=\textrm{Hom}_{A/I}(I/I^2,A/I)$$ is not helping me in finding examples.

*Added*. I am particularly interested in the case when $I$ is the ideal of a smooth curve $X$  in a variety $Y=\textrm{Spec }A$ of dimension 3.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: What do you mean by $A$ being torsion free? $A$ is even free as an $A$-module right? But thanks for the comment!

Comment: If such a map existed, then everything in $I^2$ goes to zero. So, an obvious necessary condition is that $I^2=0$. So, essentially it can never happen in your `added' part. Having such an injective map, as you can see, makes the embedding $V(I)\subset\mathrm{Spec}\, A$ not very interesting.